# fancybox onclick get id is not being passed

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

so when you click on the link,it opens a modal box and sends theid to the file requestajax.php, only problem is I dont know how to get the value of theid. theid is the id value $row['id'] since its a loop there are different ids. if I put var theid outside of the .fancybox then its not being passed. any ideas ?

Here is my code:

```
$(".cobox").fancybox({

    href : 'requestajax.php',
    type: 'ajax',   
    ajax : {
        type    : "GET",

        data    : {cid:theid},
        success: function(){ 
  }
    }


});
```

and here is the html/php :

```
<a id="<?=$row['id'];?>" class="cobox" href="#inline">
```

Answer (score 1):

got it working by writing this code :

```
$(".cobox").click(function(e) {
   var thid = this.id;
   $.fancybox({
    href : 'requestajax.php',
    type: 'ajax',   
    ajax : {
        type    : "GET",

        data    : {cid:thid},
        success: function(){ 
  }
    }


});  

            });
```